# Differentiablility of function $f(x,y)$

Tags: derivatives, multivalued-functions

Can you help me find if this function is differentiable?

$$f(x,y)={\sqrt{\frac{7}{1+|ln(x^2+y^2-2x-2y|}-\frac{1}{10}}}$$

I found domain. And I found partial derivatives (same domain). But I don't know how to prove if function is differentiable or not in general. If partial derivatives are continuous functions and have same domain as original function, does that mean function is differentiable on its domain?

Comment: If partials exist and are continuous, this is sufficient for differentiability.

Comment: On the circle $x^2+y^2-2x-2y=0$ partial derivatives go to $\infty$ thus the function is not differentiable on the border of the circle, even if the function do exist. Looks like at those points the tangent plane is parallel to $z$ axis